# Maximum value of the following function?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Given that $x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4 > 0$, what is the maximum value that the following function $f : \mathbb{R}^4 \to \mathbb{R}$ can attain ?

$$f(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4) = \frac{(x_1 - x_3)^2 + (x_2 - x_4)^2}{\sqrt{x_1^2 + x_2^2 + x_3^2 + x_4^2}}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function is not bounded from above.

For any $x_1, \varepsilon > 0$ by plugging in $(x_1, \varepsilon, \varepsilon, \varepsilon)$ we obtain:

$$f(x_1, \varepsilon, \varepsilon, \varepsilon) = \frac{(x_1 - \varepsilon)^2}{\sqrt{x_1^2 + 3\varepsilon^2}} \xrightarrow{\varepsilon\to 0} \frac{x_1^2}{\sqrt{x_1^2}} = x_1$$

So, by picking a small enough $\varepsilon$ and a large enough $x_1$, your function can attain arbitrarily large values. Therefore, the maximum does not exist.

Comment: this answer is just great ! Thanks